# JSON Deserialization to existing library C# object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am getting web service responses in JSON, the strings like this:

```
{
 "adjusted": true,
 "queryCount": 2,
 "request_id": "6a7e466379af0a71039d60cc78e72282",
 "results": [
  {
   "c": 75.0875,
   "h": 75.15,
   "l": 73.7975,
   "n": 1,
   "o": 74.06,
   "t": 1577941200000,
   "v": 135647456,
   "vw": 74.6099
  },
  {
   "c": 74.3575,
   "h": 75.145,
   "l": 74.125,
   "n": 1,
   "o": 74.2875,
   "t": 1578027600000,
   "v": 146535512,
   "vw": 74.7026
  }
 ],
 "resultsCount": 2,
 "status": "OK",
 "ticker": "AAPL"
}
```

When I use my own C# objects (below) they look like this and I reserialize fine:

```
public class Aggregates
{
    [JsonProperty("ticker")]
    public string Ticker { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("queryCount")]
    public int QueryCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resultsCount")]
    public int ResultsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("adjusted")]
    public bool Adjusted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Aggregate> Aggregatelist { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("request_id")]
    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

   public class Aggregate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The trading volume of the symbol in the given time period.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("v")]
    public object Volume { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The volume weighted average price.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("vw")]
    public double VolumeWeightedw { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The open price for the symbol in the given time period.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("o")]
    public double Open { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The close price for the symbol in the given time period.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("c")]
    public double Close { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The highest price for the symbol in the given time period.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("h")]
    public double High { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The lowest price for the symbol in the given time period.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("l")]
    public double Low { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Unix Msec timestamp for the start of the aggregate window.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("t")]
    public long StartTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of transactions in the aggregate window.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("n")]
    public int TransactionsNum { get; set; }
}
```

However, I am forced now to use a library that has its own C# object Quote instead of my Aggregate object. Redundant to say that I cannot change Quote object.

```
public class Quote : IQuote
{
    public Quote();

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
}
public interface IQuote
{
    DateTime Date { get; }
    decimal Open { get; }
    decimal High { get; }
    decimal Low { get; }
    decimal Close { get; }
    decimal Volume { get; }
}
```

I could just copy data from Aggregate to Quote for all objects but that could be millions of objects, and I have a gut feeling that it is possible to deserialize JSON directly to Quote object in a very concise way, I just could not find how...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.This code was tested in Visual Studio

```
var json=... your json

List<Quote> quotes = JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject<Aggregates>(json)
        .Aggregatelist.Select(a => new Quote
        {
            Date = UnixTimeToDateTime(a.StartTime),
            Open = (decimal)a.Open,
            High = (decimal)a.High,
            Low = (decimal)a.Low,
            Close = (decimal)a.Close,
            Volume = (decimal)a.VolumeWeightedw
        }).ToList();

public static DateTime UnixTimeToDateTime(long unixtime)
{
    var dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixtime).ToLocalTime();
}
```

output

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2020-01-02T01:30:00-03:30",
    "Open": 74.06,
    "High": 75.15,
    "Low": 73.7975,
    "Close": 75.0875,
    "Volume": 74.6099
  },
  {
    "Date": "2020-01-03T01:30:00-03:30",
    "Open": 74.2875,
    "High": 75.145,
    "Low": 74.125,
    "Close": 74.3575,
    "Volume": 74.7026
  }
]
```

And IMHO you can change your class properties from double to decimal

```
   [JsonProperty("o")]
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    ...and so on
```

than the code will not need the extra cast and you can replace

```
    Open = (decimal)a.Open,
```

with just

```
Open = a.Open,
... and so on
```

Comment: Isn't it like copying Aggregate object after JSON deserialization into newly created Quote object (just using more concise syntax)?

Comment: @Leon IMHO it is not about  to copy or not  to copy,  it is about how to convert  Json to a List<Quote>. I don't know how many times copy data from one peace of memory to another a contract resolver, custom serializer and so on. But I know that it takes a tons of code to create json from db and send  from one server to another. And amount of this code can't be even compared with amount code to convert json to the c# object. It will be thousands time difference.

Comment: I admit that this code is really cute and concise and the only one that works so far. But I will need to run some serious tests with real time data to stay with it because I am talking about converting hundreds of thousands (and maybe millions) of arrays, and Linq is know as a performance  manger... It will take me couple of days to verify.

Comment: @Leon yes, it is a good idea. You can test all answers and select the fastest algorithm. Also I think in you classes you have to change double to decimal too, it can save some time.

Comment: Thank you Serge, I will definitely let you know the timings. The other offered solutions simply do not work...

Comment: Really strange, now that I am running on real data I get exception that wasn't there before: 
System.InvalidCastException
Message: Specified cast is not valid.
Source: QuantDashboard

Comment: StackTrace:
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at QuantDashboard.WebApi.ParseQuotes(String jsonStr) in C:\Projects\QuantDashboard\QuantDashboard\WebAPI.cs:line 409
TargetSite: Skender.Stock.Indicators.Quote

Comment: @Leon I am always testing my code before posting. Where did you get this exception?

Comment: The exception is on the main deserialization line.

Comment: You will have to post json that throws an exception. Json that you posted is working properly. I tested several times.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do by extending `DefaultContractResolver`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonStr = "{'adjusted': true,'queryCount': 2,'request_id': '6a7e466379af0a71039d60cc78e72282','results': [{"+
            "'c': 75.0875,'h': 75.15,'l': 73.7975,'n': 1,'o': 74.06,'t': 1577941200000,'v': 135647456,'vw': 74.6099},"+
        "{'c': 74.3575,'h': 75.145,'l': 74.125,'n': 1,'o': 74.2875,'t': 1578027600000,'v': 146535512,'vw': 74.7026}],"+
        "'resultsCount': 2,'status': 'OK','ticker': 'AAPL'}";

        var jsonResolver = new PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver();
        jsonResolver.RenameProperty(typeof(Quote),  "Close","c");
        jsonResolver.RenameProperty(typeof(Quote), "Volume","vw");
        jsonResolver.RenameProperty(typeof(Quote),  "Open","o");
        jsonResolver.RenameProperty(typeof(Quote),  "Low","l");
        jsonResolver.RenameProperty(typeof(Quote),  "High","h");

        var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        serializerSettings.ContractResolver = jsonResolver;
        var objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Quote>>(jsonObj.SelectToken("results").ToString(), serializerSettings);
    }
}
```

This is a sample implementation

```
public class PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>> _ignores;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>> _renames;

    public PropertyRenameAndIgnoreSerializerContractResolver()
    {
        _ignores = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>>();
        _renames = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }

    public void IgnoreProperty(Type type, params string[] jsonPropertyNames)
    {
        if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
            _ignores[type] = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var prop in jsonPropertyNames)
            _ignores[type].Add(prop);
    }

    public void RenameProperty(Type type, string propertyName, string newJsonPropertyName)
    {
        if (!_renames.ContainsKey(type))
            _renames[type] = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        _renames[type][propertyName] = newJsonPropertyName;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (IsIgnored(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;
            property.Ignored = true;
        }

        if (IsRenamed(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyName, out var newJsonPropertyName))
            property.PropertyName = newJsonPropertyName;

        return property;
    }

    private bool IsIgnored(Type type, string jsonPropertyName)
    {
        if (!_ignores.ContainsKey(type))
            return false;

        return _ignores[type].Contains(jsonPropertyName);
    }

    private bool IsRenamed(Type type, string jsonPropertyName, out string newJsonPropertyName)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> renames;

        if (!_renames.TryGetValue(type, out renames) || !renames.TryGetValue(jsonPropertyName, out newJsonPropertyName))
        {
            newJsonPropertyName = null;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and simplified Quote class for this example.

```
public class Quote 
{
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had high hope for this, but it throws exception: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Skender.Stock.Indicators.Quote]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: I updated the example with exact json from the question. It works for me. Are you selecting results token?

Comment: I will try it again, although I ended up with just copying Aggregate objects to Quote objects after deserializing Aggregates... Not sure if your solution faster and whether there are internal copying is going on internally.

Comment: @Leon I appreciate if you mark the working solution as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom data contractor like so:

```
    public class QuoteDataContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        public static readonly QuoteDataContractResolver Instance = new QuoteDataContractResolver();

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(Quote))
            {
                switch (property.PropertyName)
                {
                    case "Date":
                        property.PropertyName = "d";
                        break;

                    case "Open":
                        property.PropertyName = "o";
                        break;
            
                     //and so on for all the other props
                }

            }
            return property;
        }
    }
```

And use it like so:

```
Quote q = new Quote { };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = QuoteDataContractResolver.Instance
};

//Serialize
var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(q, settings);

//Deserialize
q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quote>(jsonStr, settings);
```

Edited:
This is how the object should look like eventually:

```
public class QuoteWrapper
{
    public bool adjusted;
    public int queryCount;
    public string request_id;
    public Quote[] results;
    public int resultsCount;

    public string status;
    public string ticker;
}
```

This is the object received by the json string you supplied in your question

Working example here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/KsIXeV

Comment: I will try this tonight. It looks very promising.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is not working at all... As it is written the result is a single Quote object and it is empty. At the same time, I am not sure you noticed that I am getting JSON string which is an array of Quote objects. So I tried: List<Quote> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Quote>>(jsonStr, settings); but that threw exception...

Comment: Well I didn't put the whole solution, only 'how to do it' approach... added more info + working example